# SPFileVersion.OpenBinary() error: The specified program requires a newer version of Windows

Tags: error

Anyone seen this error before and found a solution?

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The specified program requires a newer version of Windows. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007047E) --->
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007047E): The specified program requires a newer version of Windows. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007047E)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileVersionAsByteArray(String bstrWebUrl, String bstrFileUrl, Int32 lVersion)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileVersionAsByteArray(String bstrWebUrl, String bstrFileUrl, Int32 lVersion)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileVersionAsByteArray(String bstrWebUrl, String bstrFileUrl, Int32 lVersion)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileVersion.GetFileContent()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileVersion.OpenBinary()
```

The error shows for a few large files (~25mb per version) in a 32-bit WSS3.0 SP2 environment. Also, the error only appears for Microsoft Word files - they all contain a large amount of images which explains the large file sizes.

EDIT:
The error is reproducible for selected MS Word files, the code is running from an Application Page in the _layouts folder. I cannot reproduce the problem in my environment - it only occurs in the environment of a customer.

Comment: I just learned that the customer is using MS SQL Server 2000 Enterprise (32-bit)! Have not tried that setup myself!!

Comment: Make sure it's (SQLServer 2k) patched to Service Pack 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put this down to race conditions in the situation I was in - it was inside a event receiver (ItemAdded), and I was trying to OpenBinary whilst the SPFile was still being written to the ContentDB, resulting in all sorts of unpredictable behaviour. Unfortunately, other priorities came up so I had to abandon that particular feature at the time.

Does your code execute within an EventReceiver? I think I had ideas about somehow waiting until the SPFile's apparent filesize (when read from the ContentDB) matched that of the actual filesize, but I never got round to looking into how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

please add some detail on how exactly do you get the error and is it reproducable?

What SQL version are you running on?

Are you running any custom code?

Googling reveals a few issues that may be related:

http://suguk.org/forums/thread/18052.aspx <- James is a regular on these forums so he may be able to assist
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/7d6cfd91-88d7-44f8-b21e-c740ac9a32a1
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29671319/specified-program-requires-a-newer-version-of-windows.aspx